# For non-negative $f$ such that $\int_1^\infty |f'(t)|dt < \infty$, $\sum f(k)$ and $\int_1^\infty f(t)dt$ converge or diverge together

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives

Suppose that $f\in C^1([1, \infty))$, $f>0$, and $\int_{1}^\infty |f'(t)|dt < \infty$. I want to show that $\sum_1^\infty f(k)$ and $\int_1^\infty f(t)dt$ are either both convergent or both divergent.

One approach might be to try to show that  $\lim_{n\to \infty}(\sum_1^n f(k) - \int_1^n f(t)dt)< \infty$, which is true under the additional hypothesis that $f$ is monotonically decreasing. But I haven't gotten anywhere in proving this, and I suspect it isn't true.

One thing I have come up with is that $\forall \epsilon >0$, $f$ is eventually Lipschitz with Lipschitz constant $\epsilon$, which we can see as follows: take $x_{\epsilon}$ such that $\forall x > x_{\epsilon}$ $|f'(x)|<\epsilon$. Then $\forall x,y > x_{\epsilon}$ we have $|f(x) - f(y)| = |\int_{y}^{x}f'(t)dt| \leq \int_x^y|f'(t)|dt \leq |y-x|\varepsilon$. But I'm having trouble leveraging this information into a solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\color{#C00000}{\int_k^{k+1}|f(x)-f(k)|\,\mathrm{d}x}
$$
Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\int_k^{k+1}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x-f(k)\right|
&=\left|\int_k^{k+1}(f(x)-f(k))\,\mathrm{d}x\right|\\
&\le\color{#C00000}{\int_k^{k+1}|f(x)-f(k)|\,\mathrm{d}x}\\
&=\int_k^{k+1}\left|\int_k^xf'(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\right|\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&\le\int_k^{k+1}\int_k^x|f'(t)|\,\mathrm{d}t\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_k^{k+1}\int_t^{k+1}|f'(t)|\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_k^{k+1}(k+1-t)|f'(t)|\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&\le\int_k^{k+1}|f'(t)|\,\mathrm{d}t
\end{align}
$$

Comment: OK, I see that the integrand is ultimately bounded by $\epsilon$, and that the expression is $\geq \int_1^n f(t)dt - \sum_1^n f(k)$, but I'm getting $\leq \sum \epsilon$, so I haven't quite shown convergence.

Comment: @EricAuld: I've added all but the dotting of the *i* s.

Comment: Wonderfully clear answers as always. +1.