# Is my reasoning correct about the convergence of this integral?

Tags: sequences-and-series, improper-integrals, proof-verification

The integral is $\int_1^\infty\frac{\sin{x}}{x}dx$. I know that this integral converges, but I'm wondering if this is  valid way to prove it.

> This function, if its domain is limited to $\mathbb{N}$, is identical to the sequence:
>   $$-\dfrac{2(-1)^n}{\pi{n}}$$
>   Because the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty-\frac{2(-1)^n}{\pi{n}}$ is an alternating series, we know it converges by the alternating series test. By the integral test of convergence, if the series converges, then the integral converges.

What I'm most unsure about is whether or not the integral test works in "reverse". That is, making the integral into a series and using that to determine whether or not the integral converges. Is this a sound proof?

Comment: This doesn't work; you could have nasty stuff going on between the natural numbers, and you are not able to control the integral by just the values of the integrand on $\mathbb N$. You have to use some monotonicity assumptions.

Comment: I don't understand how you evaluated $\sin(n)/n$...

Comment: @Michalis I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean how I determined that $\sin{n}/n$ converges?

Comment: You seem to be implying $\sin(n)/n = -(-1)^n\pi/(2n)$ which is wrong for many reasons.

Comment: @Michalis No, I didn't at any point say they were equal.

Comment: Oh sorry then! What do you mean with 'this function if it's domain is limited to $\mathbb{N}$ ...'. I thought you meant the function $f(x)=\sin(x)/x$.

Comment: @Michalis Well, the function $f(x)$ coincides with the sequence at all points $x=n\pi/2$, so I'm trying to use the comparison between the integral and the series to test for convergence. My reasoning is that since the series converges and the function contains all the values in the series, the function must also converge.

Comment: In general, sampling at discrete points is not enough. It is easy to find a discrete sequence of points for which we have divergence. My favourite way to do the problem is by using integration by parts, the argument is not hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comparison between the integral and series is valid if the function is monotone or if $$\int_c^\infty |f'(x)|\, dx < \infty$$(see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436382/for-non-negative-f-such-that-int-1-infty-ftdt-infty-sum-fk-a) link). You may be able to get somewhere with the second method. But the best way to go here is [Dirichlet's test](http://home.iitk.ac.in/~psraj/mth101/lecture_notes/lecture18.pdf).